# Latex: "curly N" for neighborhood in Graph Theory context

Tags: fonts, letters, alphabet

How to do the "curly N" for neighborhood  in Graph Theory context? Please see the image attached.

[image]

Comment: `\mathcal{N}` (in math-mode) perhaps?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. And you might want to check out  [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But '\mathcal' do not do the trick. Also I tried all command presented in the link below: (http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_symbols)

Comment: @sci9 Using Zapf Chancery as a mathematical alphabet is at least unfortunate, but more, simply a disaster. The font has many features which make it incompatible with spacing in mathematical typesetting. Both your original image and the reproduction by Gonzalo are ugly beyond acceptable.

Comment: an alphabet in the chancery tradition, but without the (unsuitable for math) flourishes is euler script (`texdoc euscript`), designed by hermann zapf at the urging of don knuth.  the "N" from that alphabet would seem an acceptable substitute for the intended use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This, at least the "N", is Zapf Chancery math alphabet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$\mathpzc{N}_{i}(t)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that this will produce ugly results (See [`yo's comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267235/latex-curly-n-for-neighborhood-in-graph-theory-context#comment640875_267235)) since the subscript clashes with the lower right embellishment of the "N"; one could try raising a little the subscript as I did in the example code (and perhaps was done to get the image in the question), but all and all, the result is not satisfactory; what if the subscript had been a "j"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

Ugly:
$\mathpzc{N}_{i}(t)\quad
\mathpzc{N}_{\raisebox{0.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{$\scriptstyle i$}}(t)$

Terribly ugly: $\mathpzc{N}_{j}(t)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As concluding remark, it would be better to use another glyph. [`barbara beeton's suggestion`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267235/latex-curly-n-for-neighborhood-in-graph-theory-context/267238?noredirect=1#comment640889_267238) is to use the Euler Script alphabet. Here's a comparison:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{euscript}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{T1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

$\mathpzc{N}_{i}(t)\quad\EuScript{N}_{i}(t)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Needed to say, do you really want the stroke of the letter clashing into the lower index?

Comment: @yo' Yes, that's ugly. I'm still trying to identify the font for the "i" and the "t" in the question since the clash is less noticeable with that font. Do you happen to know which font is?

Comment: No, and I don't have LaTeX here to make some tests. But the true problem is not in this font, it's in Chancery being a bad choice from the beginning, the clash in the image in the question is as bad as the one in your answer. BTW, the glyph in the question is slightly different from what you show -- any idea why?

Comment: @yo' No idea. Are they really different or is it just a result of different zooming in the images?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- the "i" and "t" look very times-ish to me.  even so, it's a mistake to try to use the "original" zapf chancery in math.  i'm sure that zapf himself would have said so.  take a look at the euler script, designed by zapf at knuth's urging.  it's clearly in the chancery tradition, but devoid of the flourishes that make "chancery" unsuitable.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, they are in Times. I added a little remark including your suggestion. Do you think the answer is better now with the final suggestion about using a different glyph?

Comment: @sci9 You're welcome. I updated my answer including some remarks born from the discussion in comments about using Zapf Chancery in maths.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- i do think it's an improvement. (it's difficult to conceive of something worse in this context.  zapf chancery is absolutely beautiful when used properly, but this is a distinct misuse.)  if something with a more decided slope is wanted, lucida calligraphy has a fine chancery-style N without the swash on the lower right, but it's proprietary.